# Detecting edges of image in android using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv

In my application , i need to capture image(coins on table ) and then detect its edges. i got to know that OpenCV works good for this scenerio. I ported OpenCV on android, installed sample CVCamera is working fine.But i didnt find how to call generic methods ? can any one tell me how to accomplish my task using OpenCV ?

Thank u,
Srinivas

Comment: have you implemented your program? I really need your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tutorials and samples on the web devoted to edge detection with opencv. For example [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut5.html) you will find one which uses opencv/canny algorithm. And [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html) you will find the opencv documentation on the topic.

I'm assuming you are using this port of opencv to Android: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidExperimental . You will find the  android-experimental/opencv/android/apps/OpenCV_SAMPLE/ the sample of canny algorithm on android.